In WSJT-X my waterfall display is not showing any signals
I had to change hard drives in my PC and now my waterfall display is not working. I DO have control of my IC-7300 via USB. I have connected the audio just like before. Am I missing a special driver or some configuration?

Your PC probably has multiple audio devices, is the correct one selected?

I have an IC-7300 as well.
The fact that rig control is working implies that you have the correct iCOM driver installed on your PC and that wsjt-x is configured for the correct serial port.
The most likely problem is on the audio side, and specifically the soundcard setting is wrong on wsjt-x. On wsjt-x choose the "File->Settings..." menu and on the popup, choose the "Audio" tab. Look at the "Soundcard:" settings. I expect the names of the IC-7300 audio devices on your PC will match mine. The "Input:" field should be "Microphone (USB Audio CODEC)" and the "Output:" field should be "Speakers (USB Audio CODEC)"
If you don't see these audio device names, I would exit wsjt-x, power down your IC-7300 (not just turn it off), and then repower it and turn it on. Bring up wstj-x and check the soundcard settings again.
One other thing is to make sure you don't have any other programs running that talk to your radio, such as fldigi.
If this isn't the problem, we will need to check the gain settings in the audio path.
